# Debugging CString in C++ 64 Bit Managed Environment Visual Studio 2012

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, 64-bit, clr, c-strings

I am pushing some older code written in Visual Studio 2008 into Visual Studio 2012. The code is MFC, /CLR, and now 64 bit. When debugging the code I found something most peculiar.  When looking at the value of a CString variable I'm met with this mess:

[image: Debugging Issue]

If you look at the variable stuff I was expecting it to have the value of "stuff" but instead I think it's pointing to it's memory address.

I've been able to recreate the problem within Visual Studio.  If I create a new project in 32 bit works fine, If I create a new project in 32 bit and managed (CLR) it works fine. If I create a new project in 64 bit it works fine. However if I create a project in both 64 bit and managed the following occurs.

I've gone through just about every Tools->Options->Debugging option available and am coming up short.  I'm hoping the hivemind has some ideas.

Comment: Do any of these alternatives work correctly: `CString stuff("stuff");` or `CString stuff(_T("stuff"));` or `CString stuff = CString(_T("stuff"));`?

Comment: Also, if you have `#define _ATL_CSTRING_EXPLICIT_CONSTRUCTORS` in your `stdafx.h`, does commenting it out change what you see while debugging?

Comment: Thanks for the response.  Apologies for the delay in my response.  For your first question:  All of your options returned the same result which is just the same as you see above.  

Interestingly. if you look at that memory space in the memory debugger the whole string is there.  So it's a a display issue but the data is otherwise safe.

Comment: I tried the second option "Remove the #define _ATL_CSTRING_EXPLICIT_CONSTRUCTORS from the stdafx.h" and it did not help with my debugging issue.  Still just the memory address showing up.

Comment: If I use managed strings rather than CStrings the debugger displays perfectly.  System::String ^ newstring = gcnew System::String("stuffstring"); for example.

Saw a reference to this back in 2013 and MS called it a bug.  I just figured it would have been fixed by now.